# Is this usecase more suitable for a relational or non relatoinal database?

Tags: database, flask

I am developing a Flask app which I can use to track my workouts. When modelling the data, I am hesitating between using a relational or non-relational database. What would be a more suitable design? Typically, the data I want to model looks as follows:

Workout: Time started, Time end, [Exercise]

Exercise: [Exercise Name, [Sets]]

Set: Weight, Repetitions

Thanks for any help in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

For a simple app like that you should use a Relational Database because you can ensure ACID compliance and it's more stable. Non-Relational Databases are better for when you're anticipating a lot of changes and growth or if you want better performance.